# Light weight scaffolding for FW/1

Tags: coldfusion, scaffolding, fw1

I am trying to create a light weight scaffolding facility for FW/1. Right now I have a file called `scaffold.cfc` in the controller which looks like

```
<cfcomponent hint="this is expected to be extended, and never used directly">



<cfscript>
function init(fw) { variables.fw = fw; }

void function home (required struct rc) output="false"  {

    /* TODO: Generic load  */

    setView("scaffold.home");
    }

void function create (required struct rc) output="false"    {

    /* TODO: Generic create  */

    setView("scaffold.create");
    }

void function show (required struct rc) output="false"  {

    /* TODO: Generic show  */

    setView("scaffold.show");
    }
```

...

```
</cfscript>


</cfcomponent>
```

I want to make sure that `index.cfm?action=scaffold.*` or `index.cfm/scaffold/*` can never ran.

Where is the best place to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could place the `scaffold.cfc` outside the `controllers` folder so FW/1 doesn't consider it to be a controller CFC (since you would only extend this, not use it directly as a controller). You could also place it in a subfolder of the `controllers` folder and, again, FW/1 would ignore it.